# MinIO API responded with message Data read 0 is shorter than the size of input buffer

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, minio

Directly putting objects from user input (`MemoryStream`) to an S3 object storage using *Min.IO* can cause a wired error of `Exception has occurred: CLR/Minio.Exceptions.UnexpectedShortReadException Exception thrown: 'Minio.Exceptions.UnexpectedShortReadException' in System.Private.CoreLib.dll: 'MinIO API responded with message=Data read 0 is shorter than the size x of input buffer.'`

```
        public async Task UploadFileAsync(IFormFile image)
        {
            using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
            {
                image.CopyTo(ms);
                var args = new Minio.DataModel.Args.PutObjectArgs { }
                        .WithBucket(bucket)
                        .WithObject("test-" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString())
                        .WithContentType(image.ContentType)
                        .WithStreamData(ms)
                        .WithObjectSize(ms.Length);
                await minioClient.PutObjectAsync(args);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The function `CopyTo` will increase the `Position` (which is a pointer) of a `MemoryStream`, regarding to the source code of *MinIO*, it will not reset the `MemoryStream` instance's pointers (which is somehow a good decision if there are multiple files stored in a `MemoryStream` and someone wants to break it in chunks.

This is their condition for the exception:

```
var bytes = await ReadFullAsync(args.ObjectStreamData, (int)args.ObjectSize).ConfigureAwait(false);
var bytesRead = bytes.Length;
if (bytesRead != (int)args.ObjectSize)
// ----------> This is the place exception accrues.
```

To solve the issue, we have to reset the pointer on our own before passing it to *MinIO Client SDK*.

The ANSWER would be simply adding the line below AFTER `CopyTo`:

```
ms.Position = 0;
```

Hope it saves your time.